# Multiple multilingual menus in Django-CMS with items rooted at /

Tags: django-cms

I'm using Django-CMS 2.3.5 on Django 1.4.5 and Python 2.7.2.

I have about 2 dozen pages which need to be presented in two or more menus in my base template.

Currently I'm using a primary menu and a footer menu.  For the primary menu, I simple created a "home" page with id 'home' and a number of children, then use `{% show_menu_below_id "home" 0 100 100 100 %}`.  Works perfectly.

For the footer-menu, I've created a fake node in the page tree called "Footer Menu" with id:footer-menu with my footer menu items as children.  Then, I use `{% show_menu_below_id "footer-menu" 0 100 100 100 %}.

Each of the pages within the menus are translated into 6 languages, including their slugs of course.

The problem lies in that my URLs for the items in the footer-menu are like "/en/footer-menu/news/".  I'm required to make this simply "/en/news/".  I tried using Advanced > Overwrite URL on footer-menu to '/', but its not allowed.

So, I use Advanced > Overwrite URL field on each sub-page to set the url to "/news".  While testing in English, I do indeed get a URL of "/en/news/", but when I switch to another language (E.g., Spanish), the url is "/es/footer-menu/noticia/".

So, what strategy should I use to permit:

1. Client-arrange-able menus - Client should be able to create/move/delete pages from menus
2. Multiple menus
3. i18N slugs and
4. root the items at "/< language >/"?

Surely I'm not the first person to want to do this, right?

All ideas welcome.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to upgrade to 2.4.x where the Overwrite URL is now distinct for each language.